# The dean of a faculty is forcing people to include his son's name in academic researches

Tags: publications, research-misconduct

This post does not include me, but recently, it came to the attention of many on a social media platform that a recently graduated doctor had made a claim that "the dean of faculty of medicine" is "forcing" people into putting the dean's son's name on their studies. The dean's son, who is under 30, has more than 30 publications with one research being cited by more than 200 on Google Scholar. This is in addition to completing two literary books and attaining 2 master degrees.

Is it possible for such a figure of achievements to exist for someone who is under 30? And what should one do in case a professor/dean/advisor attempts to exert influence/pressure to force a student to mention a relative's name in their publication?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's possible for someone under 30 to have their name legitimately on 30 publications. Authorship contributions can be relatively minor, and in fields where people work on lots of different projects it could be quite possible. By age 30 one could easily have 10+ years of research experience at different levels of study. One first-authored paper per year and two side projects would be a good level of output in many fields, but not abnormal.

Yes, it's possible for any one of those publications to be cited 200 times in some fields. Publications in certain journals are widely read and may be widely cited; if they are on a hot topic they may be widely read and cited regardless of journal. Search Google Scholar for "coronavirus" and you'll find many. It doesn't necessarily take a lot of extra *effort* to be cited so much, just some good timing and luck in the right area. Papers by more famous/respected researchers are likely to be read by more people in their field and therefore more highly cited, but their coauthors will all still be on those papers, too.

Of course it's also possible to obtain those numbers fraudulently. The numbers themselves won't tell you anything. If someone is asked to add a gift authorship they should certainly decline it.

Comment: Another situation in which it is valid is in very large scientific projects (think CERN) where there are (many) hundreds of participants in every project. Much gets written by various primary authors, but many others get an authorship because of their necessary contribution. I don't know, but suspect, that some parts of medicine and pharmaceutical research can be similar.

Comment: @Buffy Indeed, good point. I don't encounter it happening in med/pharma research quite like in high energy physics, but yes of course, some fields organize authorship much differently than others and that can completely change the interpretation of publication and citation counts.

Answer (score 9):

I had more than 30 math and math ed. papers and books published by the time I was 30. I expect that people in more applied fields usually have more publications. So 30 is not something unusual.

Comment: Hmmm. As another mathematician, I think that is pretty spectacular, actually. (Gaping in awe.)

Comment: It sounds very spectacular for math indeed, haha (or even in computer science where it's generally easier to publish papers in conferences). Congrats on your publications.

Comment: According to mathsci.net Terry Tao had 87 published papers before the age of 30.